# rename files to upload to server ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload, file-rename

I have a problem - I want to upload images to a local directory on my project in `ASP.NET` `C#` and I have succeeded.

But now I need to rename the files before uploading them to my local directory.

How I can do this this?

Comment: Did you manually upload them?

Answer (score 1):

You'll not get `Rename` method directly to rename the filename.....Instead, you can use `Move` method to act like renaming in following way:

```
System.IO.File.Move(oldFile, newFile);
```

OR, You can use `Copy` method too:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(oldFile, newFile);
System.IO.File.Delete(oldFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

it will be something like this

```
 protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    string directory = Server.MapPath("uploads");
    string fExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string fileName = "newFileName" + fExtension;
    this.FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(directory,fileName));
```

}

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine` instead of `directory + @"/" + fileName`.

Answer (score 0):

its a simple give a new file name when u save it to local

```
   string newname = "yournewname";
   string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  
   FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(uploadFolder + newname+ extension));
```

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine` instead of `uploadFolder + newname+ extension`.